# motion_planners stack: broken link

Tags: ros, sbpl, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The motion_planners stack's page contains a broken download link. Namely the "source" link refers to a non-existent svn: https:// code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planners/trunk.

For the records, also the author's personal webpage (www. cs.cmu.edu/~maxim/software.html) refers to a non-existent webpage and svn.

Thank you in advance for your help. Francesco

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55203/motion_planners-stack:-broken-link/) by [FrancescoVisin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4203/francescovisin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sorry about the broken links and the crappy documentation. We are making a push this summer to get the SBPL out of the DBack/Electric age and into the more recent past and maybe even the future :).

**updated repository:**
git clone https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl.git

I fixed the link at [www.sbpl.net](http://www.sbpl.net).

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FrancescoVisin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4203/francescovisin/) on 2013-06-17**:
Hi Ben, thank you for your answer. I am on another project right now, but in the future I might be working again with ROS and in that case I will definitely be very interested in your porting of SBPL to a more recent distribution!! Thank you for writing the git repository link, for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It probably moved to github and somebody forgot to update the source URL.

That seems worth opening a defect ticket.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FrancescoVisin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4203/francescovisin/) on 2013-02-18**:
Ok, thank you.